# Server has Crashed, How to Recover My Data from Raid-1 Configured HDDs?

Tags: hard-drive, raid-1

I was using HP ProLiant ML150 G6 with Windows Server 2008 as File Server. Server is configured with 4x250 GB RAID-1. All of a sudden electricity fluctuates and the server got crashed. Now it turns on, the powersupply is working and other led indicators show activity but no display. Please help with following questions:
1. What might be the problem? Has motherboard crashed? Is it repairable? 
2. I can see led indicators blinking on Hard Drives, Can i get my data back? And how to get my data back?
Please help.

Comment: RAID is not a backup method... It's truly a horror when this happens. Why didn't the UPS kick in and put it into autoshutdown?

Comment: Bad times...UPS also crashed...I think it was due to voltage surge

Comment: Which RAID solution did you use? Software RAID? Onboard RAID? Or a dedicated RAID controller?

Comment: The issue is resolved..amazingly by itself. No need to recover data, the server is working fine. Thanks Fiasco Labs and Daniel B for your precious time.

Comment: Wow, that's one of those nightmare producing type things. Glad it resolved!! Local business here had a close lighting strike. Can overcome all precautions. Offline backups are sometimes the only cure.